# How can I call a method once a specific BsModalRef instance is hidden?

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap, ngx-bootstrap-modal

In the past when working with modals, I've come across a pattern that returns a ModalRef object that has a promise on it that is resolved or rejected when the modal is closed or dismissed.

Looking at the [documentation for the BsModalRef](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals#bs-modal-ref) in Ngx-Bootstrap, there does not appear to be any way to track whether that modal reference has been closed or dismissed.

Instead they seem to recommend subscribing to an `onHidden()` event on the BsModalService. Unfortunately this doesn't work for me, as it will fire the event when any modal is hidden. I only want to react to a specific modal instance being hidden.

Is there any way for me to do this?

I've considered using Rxjs' `take()` operator to only take the first event fired after subscribing to the `onHidden` Observable, but this feels a bit hacky.

```
const modalRef = modalService.show(RedirectToHomeModalComponent);

const returnHome = () => console.log('Returning home');

this.bsModalService.onHidden.pipe(take(1), returnHome);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can subscribe any Eventmitter from content of your modal.

*on modal.component.ts*

```
hideEvent: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

onSomeFunction(){
    this.hideEvent.next(value);
}

ngOnDestroy(){
    this.hideEvent.next(); // modal is closed without any data.
}
```

*on parent.component.ts*

```
const modalRef = modalService.show(RedirectToHomeModalComponent);
this.modalRef.content.hideEvent.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(value => {
    if(value){ // closed with a value.
      ... do something
    }
    else { // closed via backdrop or something else
      ... do something
    }
});
```